# How to Display Post Expiring plugin on posts data table wordpress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on WordPress using posts data table WordPress plugin and im using 
Post Expiring plugin i want to display the expire post data to data table WordPress.

```
                $post_data_trans = array( 
                '{id}' => $_post->ID, 
                '{title}' => $title, 
                '{category}' => get_the_category_list( ', ', '', $_post->ID ), 
                '{date}' => get_the_date( $date_format, $_post ),
                '{expiring}' => get_the_date( $date_format, $post_id, 'expire_date' ),
                '{author}' => $author, 
                '{content}' => $this->get_post_content( $args['content_length'] ) 
            );
```

this code for posts data table wordpress plugin I'm using expiring column from Post Expiring plugin, and this is the code for post expiring

```
if( $column_name === 'expiring' ){
        $postexpired = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'postexpired', true );
        if( preg_match("/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/", $postexpired) ) {
            $postexpired .= ' 00:00';
        }
        echo !empty($postexpired) ? $postexpired : __('Never');
    }
```

and i get just the Date for post not the expiring date please any one can help me please